# Production system running JBoss clustering

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cluster-computing

What are some of the largest systems that use JBoss clustering? What are the specs/config?

I want to know whether JBoss cluster is really scalable or not.

Thanks

Comment: How is anyone supposed to give a good answer to this?

Comment: All I was hoping was someone who had experienced in JBoss clustering and the system was in production, could maybe share the knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat publicly lists 92 customers using Enterprise App Platform at http://customers.redhat.com/category/red-hat-jboss-solutions/jboss-enterprise-middleware/jboss-enterprise-platforms/jboss-enterprise-application-platform/

Some that mention clustering are:

- Nationwide Mutual Insurance
- Lifespring Hospitals SBI Life
- Insurance Booz Allen Hamilton
- SwissCom Florida Hospital

Some materials downloadable from JBoss World 2010 at http://www.redhat.com/promo/summit/2010/presentations/jbossworld/ you might useful are:

- Dynamic Clusters with Apache httpd, Mod-Cluster, & JBoss
- JBoss in the Trenches